# Vue.JS + Django issue, it wouldn't let me update my userprofile from the dashboard(I get no errors, yet my database doesn't update)

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, database, vue.js

So I am working on this time tracking app for myself, to learn Django and Vue.js, I found a tutorial from Code with Stein. I got stuck at editing the profile part from the tutorial. I get no errors, yet there are no changes made to my username or email(the changes don't even apply to my admin dashboard or database). The thing is that I get no error, which leaves me completely in the dust. I used Python, Django, Vue.JS, and soon SaaS if I find a resolution for this issue.

So here is my code in project/apps/userprofile/templates/userprofile/signup.html

```
{% extends 'core/base.html' %}
<!-- Extends the base template 'base.html' -->

{% block title %}Sign Up | {% endblock %}
<!-- Sets the page title to "Sign Up" -->

{% block content %}
<!-- Begins the content block -->

<section class="hero is-medium is-light is-bold">
    <!-- Creates a hero banner -->
    <div class="hero-body">
        <div class="container">
            <h1 class="title">Sign Up</h1>
            <h2 class="subtitle">To get started you need an account.</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<div class="columns" id="signup-app">
    <!-- Creates a container with two columns -->
    <div class="column is-6 is-offset-3">
        <form method="post" action="." class="mt-6" v-on:submit="validateForm" novalidate>
            <!-- Sign-up form -->
            {% csrf_token %}
            <!-- Generates a CSRF token input field -->
            
            {% if form.errors %}
                <div class="notification is-danger">
                    {{ form.non_field_errors }}
                    <!-- Displays non-field errors -->

                    {% for field in form %}
                        {% if field.errors %}{{ field.label }}: {{ field.errors|striptags }}{% endif %}
                        <!-- Displays field-specific errors -->
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            {% endif %}
            
            <div class="notification is-danger" v-if="errors.length">
                <p v-for="error in errors">
                    [[ error ]]
                </p>
            </div>
            <!-- Displays Vue.js errors -->
            
            <div class="field">
                <label>E-mail</label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input type="email" name="username" id="id_username" class="input" v-model="username">
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Email input field -->
            
            <div class="field">
                <label>Password</label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input type="password" name="password1" id="id_password1" class="input" v-model="password1">
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Password input field -->
            
            <div class="field">
                <label>Repeat Password</label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input type="password" name="password2" id="id_password2" class="input" v-model="password2">
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Confirm password input field -->
            
            <ul class="password-helt-text">
                <li v-if="password1.length < 8">Your password must contain at least 8 characters.</li>
                <li v-if="!isNaN(password1)">Your password can't be entirely numeric.</li>
            </ul>
            <!-- Password validation messages -->
            
            <div class="field">
                <div class="control">
                    <button class="button is-success">Sign Up</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Submit button -->
            
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}

{% block scripts %}
<!-- Begins the scripts block -->
    <script>
        const SignupApp = {
            // Vue app configuration
            data() {
                return{
                    username: '',
                    password1: '',
                    password2: '',
                    errors: []
                }
            },
            delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
            methods: {
                validateForm(e) {
                    this.errors = []

                    if (!this.validateEmail(this.username)) {
                        this.errors.push('Your e-mail address is not valid!')
                    }

                    if (this.password1 === '') {
                        this.errors.push('Your password is missing')
                    }

                    if (this.password1.length < 8) {
                        this.errors.push('Your password must be at least 8 characters')
                    }

                    if (!isNaN(this.password1)) {
                        this.errors.push('Your password can\'t be entirely numeric')
                    }

                    if (this.password1 !== this.password2) {
                        this.errors.push('Your passwords do not match!')
                    }

                    if (this.errors.length) {
                        e.preventDefault()
                        return false
                    } else {
                        return true
                    }
                },
                validateEmail(email) {
                    if (/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/.test(email)) {
                        return true
                    }
                    return false
                }
            }
        }

        Vue.createApp(SignupApp).mount('#signup-app')
        // Creates a Vue app and mounts it to the '#signup-app' element
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Followed by the code in project/apps/userprofile/views.py

```
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth import login
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

# Import models
from .models import Userprofile

# Views

@login_required
def myaccount(request):
    
    # This view is responsible for rendering the 'myaccount' page.
    # It requires the user to be logged in, as indicated by the @login_required decorator.
    
    return render(request, 'userprofile/myaccount.html')

@login_required
def edit_profile(request):
    
    # This view is responsible for rendering the 'edit_profile' page and handling the form submission.
    # It allows the user to edit their profile information.
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Update the user's profile information based on the submitted form data
        request.user.first_name = request.POST.get('first_name', '')
        request.user.last_name = request.POST.get('last_name', '')
        request.user.email = request.POST.get('email', '')
        request.user.save()

        # Show a success message to the user
        messages.info(request, 'The changes were saved!')

        # Redirect the user to the 'myaccount' page
        return redirect('myaccount')
    
    # Render the 'edit_profile' page with the current user's information
    return render(request, 'userprofile/edit_profile.html')


def signup(request):
    
    # This view is responsible for rendering the 'signup' page and handling the user registration.
    # It uses the Django UserCreationForm to handle the registration form.
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            # Create a new user based on the submitted form data
            user = form.save()
            user.email = user.username
            user.save()

            # Create a user profile for the newly registered user
            userprofile = Userprofile.objects.create(user=user)

            # Log in the user
            login(request, user)

            # Redirect the user to the 'frontpage'
            return redirect('frontpage')
    
    else:
        # Display an empty registration form
        form = UserCreationForm()

    # Render the 'signup' page with the registration form
    return render(request, 'userprofile/signup.html', {'form': form})
```

Then I created my login.html and myaccount.html, to login and manage the account. The manage.html file is supposed to be like a dashboard, where from there I click a button that leads me to an edit profile form, here is the code in project/apps/userprofile/templates/userprofile/edit_profile.html

```
{% extends 'core/base.html' %}

{% block title %}Edit Profile | {% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <!-- Breadcrumb navigation -->
    <nav class="breadcrumb" aria-label="breadcrumbs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
            <li><a href="{% url 'myaccount' %}">My Account</a></li>
            <li class="is-active"><a href="{% url 'edit_profile' %}" aria-current="page"></a>Edit Profile</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="columns">
        <div class="column is-4">
            <h1 class="title">Edit Profile</h1>

            <!-- Edit profile form -->
            <form method="post" action="." enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}

                <!-- First Name field -->
                <div class="field">
                    <label>First Name</label>
                    
                    <div class="control">
                        <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" class="input"{% if request.user.first_name %} value="{{ request.user.first_name }}" {% endif %}>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Last Name field -->
                <div class="field">
                    <label>Last Name</label>
                    
                    <div class="control">
                        <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" class="input"{% if request.user.last_name %} value="{{ request.user.last_name }}" {% endif %}>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Email field -->
                <div class="field">
                    <label>Email</label>
                    
                    <div class="control">
                        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="input"{% if request.user.email %} value="{{ request.user.email }}" {% endif %}>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Save Changes button -->
                <div class="field">
                    <div class="control">
                        <button class="button is-success">Save Changes</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
            
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

So the code is expected to run just as exactly as in this [Code With Stein Tutorial on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_wCsCIg1cAk&list=PLpyspNLjzwBkm7Y28Gma4F9hl2wpuypgp&index=10) at the minute 40:35. The exact moment where I got stuck, because my profile doesn't update by any means, yet I get no errors, which is weird, because I don't know where exactly to look to fix it. I am kinda new in coding so thank you in advance!